# Load ajax dialog before form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

How can I disable form submit using ajax? The user must click first the button in the ajax dialog before the form will be submitted.

```
//on form submit 
//I'm using input type submit and not button (as much as possible, I don't want to change that)

 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?=url::base(TRUE)?>prompt",
            data: $('#formname').serialize(),
            async: false,
            success: function(response){
                $("#dialogpromt").html(response);
                $("#dialogpromt").dialog({
                    autoOpen: true, 
                    height: 'auto', 
                    width: '100', 
                    resizable: 'false',
                    dialogClass: 'dFixed'                    
                });        
                 //onlcick event would change a hidden field to '1' 
                 //works fine
            },

        });


        //Is there a way I can ensure that the dialog above is closed first before the below lines will execute?
        if(document.getElementById('submitInd').value == "0")
             return false; 
        else
             return true;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it is necessary to call this action on form submit? there is another way for do? let me know

Comment: yes, this action is needed on form submit.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("Your Submit button Id").click(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault(); // this will be used to stop the reloading the page 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?=url::base(TRUE)?>prompt",
        data: $('#formname').serialize(),
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function () { /// use beforeSend to open a dialog box 

            $("#dialogpromt").dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                height: 'auto',
                width: '100',
                resizable: 'false',
                dialogClass: 'dFixed'
            });


        },
        success: function (response) {
            $("#dialogpromt").html(response);

            //tried the if else here, no luck.
            //the dialog will just load but the form will still continue to submit                             
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: @me_an  u mean reloading the page ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to make buttons not submit.  The way I learned when I started using forms was to use spans instead of buttons.

A better, simpler way, because it allows you to keep your button structure, is to simply write

```
<button type='button'>....</button>
```

I'm not sure exactly what it does, but including the `type='button`, as opposed to the `type='submit'` which is default in forms, suppresses the default form submit action.

There are other ways to change this using javascript, such as manually suppressing the default action, not even using a form in the first place and instead wrapping the items in a div with the class 'form', and a ton of other versatile ways that fit your needs.